# What is the efficient way to resize/process image and upload to s3 in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am fairly new to django. I was wondering what would be the best approach to process an image file and upload to s3. I could think of a couple of approaches but not sure which one to pick. They are as follows: 1) Upload raw unprocessed image directly to s3 from client(mobile app), resize/process it (using Celery) and then replace the original file with the processed one. 2) Send raw image to django, process it and then upload to s3. Thank you.

Comment: If you upload  images to s3, a lambda function can be automatically invoked to resize them by means of s3 event notifications. Could be the eases and most scalable way of doing this.

Comment: @Marcin that's an option for sure but budget problem and adds an extra moving part I think.